# Failed to instantiate objects: only the first is created

Tags: java

Whats up guys !

I have a class in Java which is a server, I put this server class, the argument port, for example if I call this class I would like: new Server (5000); 5000 is the argument of this server class, so I created a new frame with a button class, and action of this button I call this class server 5 times, but with different arguments and looked like this:

```
  Servidor servidor = new Servidor(5000); //Port number argument
    Servidor servidor1 = new Servidor(5001);
    Servidor servidor2 = new Servidor(5002);
    Servidor servidor3 = new Servidor(5003);
    Servidor servidor4 = new Servidor(5004);
```

But the problem is that when I click the button, the only server that initiates the first is on port 5000, I've done the debug here and noticed that only the first statement is executed, the other 4 are not, why is that?

I've tried to do so:

```
    new Servidor(5000);
    new Servidor(5001);
    new Servidor(5002);
    new Servidor(5003);
    new Servidor(5004);
```

Still does not work, I did the debug in both cases and only the server port 5000 is started, someone help? The code have a two while this is a problem right ? But i can fix this, the code of server :

```
public class Servidor {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;
private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapOnline = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();
public int porta;

// nova lista para armazenar todas as janelas ativas
private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapJanelaLista = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
int horas = data.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutos = data.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int segundos = data.get(Calendar.SECOND);

public Servidor(int porta) {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
        System.out.println("Servidor "+ porta + " Online ");

        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);

        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}

private class ListenerSocket implements Runnable {

    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;

    public ListenerSocket(Socket socket) {
        try {
            this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Mensageiro message = null;
        try {
            while ((message = (Mensageiro) input.readObject()) != null) {
                Acao action = message.getAcao();

                if (action.equals(Acao.CONNECT)) {
                    boolean isConnect = conectar(message, output);
                    if (isConnect) {
                        mapOnline.put(message.getNome(), output);
                        enviarOnline();
                        enviarJanelaLista();
                        System.out.println(message.getNome() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + " Entrou ");
                    }
                } else if (action.equals(Acao.DISCONNECT)) {
                    desconectar(message, output);
                    enviarOnline();
                    enviarJanelaLista();

                    return;
                } else if (action.equals(Acao.SEND_ONE)) {
                    enviarUm(message);
                } else if (action.equals(Acao.SEND_ALL)) {
                    enviarTodos(message);
                } else if (action.equals(Acao.DISCONNECT_JANELA_LISTA)) { // faz a conexao para a janela da lista
                    // remove a janela da lista
                    mapJanelaLista.remove(message.getNome());
                    // formamos o fim do while (da thread referente) para esta janela
                    message = null;
                } else if (action.equals(Acao.CONNECT_JANELA_LISTA)) { // desconecta a janela da lista

                    //adiciona a janela na lista
                    mapJanelaLista.put(message.getNome(), output);
                    enviarJanelaLista();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            desconectar(message, output);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private boolean conectar(Mensageiro message, ObjectOutputStream output) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
        if (kv.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(message.getNome())) {
            message.setText("NO");
            enviar(message, output);
            return false;
        }

    }

    if (mapOnline.size() == 0) {
        message.setText("YES");
        enviar(message, output);
        return true;
    } else {
        message.setText("YES");
        enviar(message, output);
        return true;
    }

    // return false;
}

private void desconectar(Mensageiro message, ObjectOutputStream output) {
    // como temos agora 2 tipos de mensagem, do chat e da janela, precisamos fazer uns testes extras
    if (message != null) {
        // vamos aqui retirar um cliente do chat
        if (mapOnline.containsKey(message.getNome())) {
            mapOnline.remove(message.getNome());
            enviarOnline();
            enviarJanelaLista();
        }

        // vamos aqui retirar um janela de lista
        if (mapJanelaLista.containsKey(message.getNome())) {
            mapJanelaLista.remove(message.getNome());
        }
        System.out.println(message.getNome() + " " + new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + " Saiu ");
    }
}

private void enviar(Mensageiro message, ObjectOutputStream output) {
    try {
        output.writeObject(message);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void enviarUm(Mensageiro message) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
        if (kv.getKey().equals(message.getNomeReservado())) {
            try {
                kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void enviarTodos(Mensageiro message) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
        if (!kv.getKey().equals(message.getNome())) {
            message.setAcao(Acao.SEND_ONE);
            try {
                kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void enviarOnline() {
    Set<String> setNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
        setNames.add(kv.getKey());
    }

    Mensageiro message = new Mensageiro();
    message.setAcao(Acao.USERS_ONLINE);
    message.setSetOnline(setNames);

    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
        message.setNome(kv.getKey());
        try {
            kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

// esse metodo atualiza a lista de clientes ativos no chat para as janelas da lista que estão abertas
private void enviarJanelaLista() {
    Set<String> setNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapOnline.entrySet()) {
        setNames.add(kv.getKey());
    }

    Mensageiro message = new Mensageiro();
    message.setAcao(Acao.USERS_ONLINE);
    message.setSetOnline(setNames);

    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> kv : mapJanelaLista.entrySet()) {
        message.setNome(kv.getKey());
        try {
            kv.getValue().writeObject(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks !

Comment: the while(true) in the first server blocks anything else from happening, including creating other servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite loop in the constructor is blocking so no further objects can be created. To handle this situation you'll need to use [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) and separate initialization from execution.

For instance, you could modify the `Servidor` class so that it implements [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html):

```
public class Servidor implements Runnable {

    ...
    public Servidor(int porta) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Put looping code here
    }        
}
```

Then you can launch each instance in its own thread:

```
new Thread(servidor).start();
new Thread(servidor1).start();
// etc
```

Comment: Who's is the man ? Who's is the man ? You are the man ! Thanks bro !

Comment: Before I was running several servers, I run many applications, when I accessed de Manager task, I noticed that each consumed nearly 30 MB de RAM per server, so if I ran 100 servers would be 30 * 100 = 3 GB!!! Now this way you taught me it runs all in one application and consumes an average of 40 MB or 50 MB!!! I saved a lot of memory! Very good my friend! When you need I will always be here!

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (true) {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();

        new Thread(new ListenerSocket(socket)).start();
    }
```

Infinite loop. So it wont go beyond first initialization.